# How to remove the first row while inserting a csv into mysql using shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I'm using the below query to insert data  from csv into mysql in shell script.I neeed to remove the first line ie,the header names while inserting without mentioning their names

```
for _csv_file in ${_csv_files[@]}
do
export IFS=","
cat  $_csv_file | while read a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v; do  mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db << eof 
INSERT INTO \`csv_temp_table\`
 (\`ProductType\`,\`ProductTypea\`,\`ProductTypeb\`,
\`ProductTypec\`,\`ProductTyped\`,\`ProductTypee\`,
\`ProductTypef\`,\`ProductTypge\`,\`ProductTypeh\`,
\`ProductTypeh\`,\`ProductTypej\`,\`ProductTypke\`,
\`ProductTypel\`,\`ProductTypem\`,\`ProductTypen\`,
\`ProductTypeo\`,\`ProductTyppe\`,\`ProductTypeq\`,
\`ProductTyper\`,\`ProductTypes\`,\`ProductTypet\`,
\`ProductTypeu\`) VALUES   ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i',
'$j','$k','$l','$m','$n','$o','$p','$q','$r','$s','$t','$u','$v',); 
eof
done 
done
exit;
```

Please help me accomplish that.Thank you.

Comment: Replace `cat $_csv_file` by `tail -n +2 $_csv_file` ?

Comment: On another note, quote your variables: `$_csv_file` -> `"$_csv_file"`, `${_csv_files[@]}` -> `"${_csv_files[@]}"` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command which gives you quite interesting options to read different CSV styles into the database. So you need no special script for that purpose. It is definitely worth a look!

part of the man page for your request:

> The IGNORE number LINES option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use IGNORE 1 LINES to skip over an initial header line containing column names:

Comment: I would +1 this. A custom bash script may break in certain corner cases. These dedicated tools are usually tested for these corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do

```
for _csv_file in ${_csv_files[@]}
do
export IFS=","
tail -n +2 $_csv_file| while read a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v; do  mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db << eof 
INSERT INTO \`csv_temp_table\`
(\`ProductType\`,\`ProductTypea\`,\`ProductTypeb\`,
\`ProductTypec\`,\`ProductTyped\`,\`ProductTypee\`,
\`ProductTypef\`,\`ProductTypge\`,\`ProductTypeh\`,
\`ProductTypeh\`,\`ProductTypej\`,\`ProductTypke\`,
\`ProductTypel\`,\`ProductTypem\`,\`ProductTypen\`,
\`ProductTypeo\`,\`ProductTyppe\`,\`ProductTypeq\`,
\`ProductTyper\`,\`ProductTypes\`,\`ProductTypet\`,
\`ProductTypeu\`)
VALUES('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i','$j','$k','$l','$m','$n','$o','$p','$q','$r','$s','$t','$u','$v',);
eof
done 
done
exit;
```